# Why do `key in dict` and `key in dict.keys()` have the same output?

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to search the keys in a dictionary, but I forgot to add the `keys()` function. I still got the expected answer.

Why is the result the same for these two expressions?

```
key in dict
```

and

```
key in dict.keys()
```

Comment: Have you consulted [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)?

Comment: @Shashank `<dict>.__iter__` isn't the same as `<dict>.keys()` -- in Python 2, `keys` returns a list,  in Python 3, `keys` returns a "view".  In Python 2, `<dict>.__iter__` is equivalent to `<dict>.iterkeys()`.  Also, you don't need to use a metaclass or innerclass in an object to implent `__iter__`.

Comment: I realise that this is just an example, but _please_ don't use `dict` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in `dict` type. The same goes for `list`, `str`, `set`, etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To understand why `key in dct` returns the same result as `key in dct.keys()` one needs to look in the past. Historically in Python 2, one would test the existence of a *key* in dictionary `dct` with [`dct.has_key(key)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key). This was changed for [Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-234-iterators), when the preferred way became `key in dct`, which basically did the same thing:

> In a minor related change, the `in` operator now works on dictionaries, so `key in dict`  is now equivalent to `dict.has_key(key)`

The behaviour of `in` is implemented internally in terms of the `__contains__` dunder method. Its behaviour is documented in the [Python language reference - 3 Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__):

> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in `self`, false otherwise. **For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs.**
>   For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`, see this section in the language reference.

(emphasis mine; dictionaries in Python are mapping objects)

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), the `has_key` method was removed altogether and now there *the* correct way to test for the existence of a key is solely `key in dict`, as documented.

---

In contrast with the 2 above, `key in dct.keys()` has *never been the correct* way of testing whether a key exists in a dictionary.
The result of both your examples is indeed the same, however `key in dct.keys()` is slightly slower on Python 3 and is abysmally slow on Python 2.

`key in dct` returns true, if the `key` is found as a key in the `dct` in almost constant time operation - it does not matter whether there are two or a million keys - its time complexity is constant on average case (**O(1)**)

`dct.keys()` in Python 2 creates a `list` of all keys; and in Python 3 a [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) of keys; both of these objects understand the `key in x`. With Python 2 it works like for any *iterable*; the values are iterated over and `True` is returned as soon as one value is equal to the given value (here `key`).

In practice, in Python 2 you'd find `key in dct.keys()` much slower than `key in dict` (`key in dct.keys()` scales linearly with the number of keys - its time complexity is **O(n)** - both `dct.keys()`, which builds a list of all keys, and [`key in key_list`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) are **O(n)**)

In Python 3, the `key in dct.keys()` won't be much slower than `key in dct`as the [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) does not make a list of the keys, and the access still would be **O(1)**, however in practice it would be slower by at least a constant value, and it is 7 more characters, so there is usually practically no reason to use it, even if on Python 3.

Comment: The time complexity of running key in dict vs key in dict.keys() was valuable

Answer (score 4):

[Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) dictates that generally a membership test are normally implemented as an iteration through a sequence unless a container object supplies the special method  [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) .

As mentioned further in the document, for objects that does not implement the  [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)  special method, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`.

Its important to know that for dictionaries, `dict.keys()` returns <strike>either an iterator</strike> either a dictionary view **(Python 3.X)** or a sequence (more precisely a list), in **Python (2.X)**. Membership test for a sequence/list is an `O(n)` complexity  where as for a dictionary like object which is implemented as a hash map, or a dictionary view which supports operation like supports operations like membership test and iteration has a complexity of O(1).

So for Python 2.X, there is a distinct difference in terms of what both does, that might impact performance, where as for Python 2.X, the only overhead is an extra function call.

In any case, it is always preferred to use the membership on the dict object rather than using the membership test on a dictionary view or a sequence which is returned by `dict.keys`