# Loop not iterating correctly when using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

The goal of the loop is to add 1 to the value of the dictionary when the key in the dictionary (dictionary being WorldSeriesWins in the code) is equal to t from a list called Team. It seems to not be iterating correctly as I believe I coded something in wrong.

Here is the portion of the code that I don't believe is correct:

```
WorldSeriesWins = {}
for t in Team:
   WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1
   if t == WorldSeriesWins.keys():
        WorldSeriesWins[t] +=1
   else:
       WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1
```

The results:

```
 {'Boston Americans': 1, 'New York Giants': 1, 'Chicago White Sox': 1, 'Chicago Cubs': 1, 'Pittsburgh Pirates': 1, 'Philadelphia Athletics': 1, 'Boston Red Sox': 1, 'Boston Braves': 1, 'Cincinnati Reds': 1, 'Cleveland Indians': 1, 'New York Yankees': 1, 'Washington Senators': 1, 'St. Louis Cardinals': 1, 'Detroit Tigers': 1, 'Brooklyn Dodgers': 1, 'Milwaukee Braves': 1, 'Los Angeles Dodgers': 1, 'Baltimore Orioles': 1, 'New York Mets': 1, 'Oakland Athletics': 1, 'Philadelphia Phillies': 1, 'Kansas City Royals': 1, 'Minnesota Twins': 1, 'Toronto Blue Jays': 1, 'Atlanta Braves': 1, 'Florida Marlins': 1, 'Arizona Diamondbacks': 1, 'Anaheim Angels': 1}
```

This would mean that there aren't any duplicates, but there definitely are based on the list. I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could someone assist me?

Comment: Every time you see a `t` you reset it to `1` because `WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1` is inside the loop.

Comment: I agree with @MarkMeyer. I think you should delete line 3. I also think your `if` is never going to be `true` so you're always in your `else` case. I think you need something like `if t in WorldSeriesWins.keys():` instead.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! So, list() creates an iterable list of keys from the WorldSeriesWins dictionary? Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @QMan5 I made it overly complicated at first, but tested on my machine and refined the first comment. It's not necessary to wrap it in `list(...)` like I first thought since the output of `keys()` is already iterable. The key change is that you want to check for the `in` condition and not the `==` condition. Your `t` `str` will not be `==` to the output of `WorldSeriesWins.keys()` because that method does not return a `str`.

Comment: It would probably be a lot simpler to just use `from collections import Counter; WorldSeriesWins = Counter(Team)`

Answer (score 2):

You always reset the number of wins for the team to 1. Just leave out the third line.

Also, to check if the team is already in the dictionary, use `in`, not `==`.

And finally, it's enough (and much more effective) to use `a in dict` instead of `a in dict.keys()`, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314342/7292139) for more details.

```
WorldSeriesWins = {}
for t in Team:
   if t in WorldSeriesWins:
        WorldSeriesWins[t] +=1
   else:
       WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1
```

Also, it might be more readable to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) from Python standard library:

```
import collections
WorldSeriesWins = collections.defaultdict(int) # call int() (--> 0) to create unknown values
for t in Team:
    WorldSeriesWinds[t] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WorldSeriesWins = {}
for t in Team:
   # WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1
   if t in WorldSeriesWins.keys():
        WorldSeriesWins[t] +=1
   else:
       WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1
```

Change `t == World...:` to `t in World...:`

Also, the first `WorldSeriesWins[t] = 1` keeps resetting your counts.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by the `Counter` class in the collections library:

```py
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(Team)
WorldSeriesWins = dict(c)
```

or the one liner `WorldSeriesWins = dict(Counter(Team))`